# Validate sessions in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have an application developed using ASP.NET Core 5 MVC written in C#. I am using OTP verification to enable access to a the pages as highlighted below:

```
public const string SessionKeyName = "CurrentOTP";

public IActionResult GenerateOTP(OTPData mydata)
{
    .
    .
    HttpContext.Session.SetString(SessionKeyName, mydata.OTP);
    return RedirectToAction("EnterOTP", "Home");
}

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult VerifyOTP(string otp,OTPData mydata2)
{
        bool result = false;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Session.GetString(SessionKeyName)))
        {
            HttpContext.Session.SetString(SessionKeyName, mydata2.OTP);
        }

        var sessionOTP = HttpContext.Session.GetString(SessionKeyName);

        if (otp == sessionOTP)
        {
            result = true;
        }

        return Json(result);
}
```

My issue however is that any user can access any webpage by simply inputting the full URL into the address bar. How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use the `[authorize]` attribute on your endpoints and add some form of authentication to your website by configuring the services in your startup.cs with `services.AddAuthentication`.
I'd actually suggest using the [azure OTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/one-time-passcode) and dropping your custom setup entirely since the first rule of IT security is to never make it yourself

Answer (score 0):

```
public const string SessionKeyName = "CurrentOTP";

public IActionResult GenerateOTP(OTPData mydata)
{
    .
    .
    HttpContext.Session.SetString(SessionKeyName, mydata.OTP);
    return RedirectToAction("EnterOTP", "Home");
}
```

**Changes in your Method Below**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult VerifyOTP(string otp)
{
        bool result = false;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Session.GetString(SessionKeyName)))
        {
            var sessionOTP = HttpContext.Session.GetString(SessionKeyName);
            
            if (otp == sessionOTP)
            {
                result = true;
            }
        }
        return Json(result);        
}
```